# Print out Data Type Ranges to C# Console

Tags: c#, types, console, primitive-types

I remember myself that there was a method to print out the Data Type Ranges in C#.

I thought it would be `int intSize = sizeof(int);` but it only prints out "4 Bytes". I´d like to print out the range in number, from the lowest **–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647**

Hope you can help me out to remember myself

Answer (score 1):

Use int.MinValue and int.MaxValue.

Comment: Yes! Thats is it. Thank you, forgot such simple things...

Answer (score 1):

You need [`int.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.minvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and  [`int.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} to {1}", int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
```

You can create a generic method like :*(no error checking and no constraints)*

```
class ValueRange<T>
{
    public static string GetRange()
    {
        FieldInfo maxValueField = typeof(T).GetField("MaxValue", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        FieldInfo minValueField = typeof(T).GetField("MinValue", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        return string.Format("{0} to {1}", minValueField.GetValue(null), maxValueField.GetValue(null));
    }
}
```

and then call it like:

```
string str = ValueRange<int>.GetRange();
```

You will get: `str = "-2147483648 to 2147483647"`

For `double`

```
string str = ValueRange<double>.GetRange();
```

and you will get: `str = "-1.79769313486232E+308 to 1.79769313486232E+308"`